# Изменение согласных после приставок

Tags: орфография

Прошу разъяснить различия в правописании слов: **сверхъестественный** и **сверхизысканный** - почему в одном есть твердый знак, а в другом нет, а также слово подынтегральный - почему меняем **и** на **ы**?

Answer (score 1):

Почему *сверхизысканный*, читаем

**[§ 29. Буквы ы и и после приставок](http://old-rozental.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=3238)**

> После приставок *меж-* и *сверх-* в начале корня сохраняется буква
>   ***и*** (так как по общему правилу после шипящих и заднеязычных буква ***ы*** не пишется): *межинститутский, межимпериалистический, сверхизысканный, сверхиндустриализация.* Так же: *двухимпульсный,
>   трёхионный, четырехигольный* и т. п.

Почему *подынтегральный* (параграф тот же):

> После приставок, оканчивающихся на согласную, в корне вместо
>   начального ***и*** пишется буква ***ы*** в соответствии с
>   произношением: *подыграть, разыграть, сыграть ← играть; отыскать,
>   подыскать, разыскать ← искать; безыдейный ← идейный; безындукционный ←
>   индукционный; подынтегральный ← интегральный; предыстория ← история,
>   предыюльский ← июльский.*

Почему *сверхъестественный:*

> Разделительный ***Ъ*** (твердый знак) нужно писать ***на стыке
>   приставки и корня, если приставка оканчивается на согласную, а корень
>   слова начинается буквами Е, Ё, Ю, Я.*** Например: ПОДЪЕЗД, ИЗЪЯВИТЬ,
>   ИНЪЕКЦИЯ, ТРАНСЪЕВРОПЕЙСКИЙ. Кроме этого, разделительный Ъ пишется в
>   сложных словах с числительными: ДВУХЪЯРУСНЫЙ, ТРЕХЪЯЗЫЧНЫЙ.

Answer (score 1):

**Сверхъестественный**

Разделительный твердый знак (как и разделительный мягкий знак) фонетически обозначает **звук Й в положении между согласным и гласным**, поэтому он пишется перед буквами  Е, Ё, Ю, Я, содержащими звук Й. Сравнить: сверхактивный, нет разделительного знака.

**Сверхизысканный**

**Обычно И в корне меняется на Ы в большинстве случаев** (играть – обыграть, розыгрыш, итог – подытожить,  история – предыстория, идея – безыдейный, идущий – предыдущий, искусный – безыскусный), но только не после Ж и Х.

В этом случае отсутствие замены Ы на И связано с тем, что в русском языке отсутствуют подобные написания по следующим причинам: **во-первых**, после заднеязычных   Г, К, Х обычно пишется И,  но не Ы : гитара, хитрый, кинжал; во-вторых, после Ж пишется И в соответствии с орфограммой ЖИ-ШИ.
Таким образом, выбор И в корне в данном случае делается **с целью избежать сочетаний букв, которые в языке обычно не встречаются.**